# Secure Web Authentication and API access

Tags: api, authentication, ssl, https, hmacsha1

I want to design a web application which guarantees secure authentication and gives API access only to the authorised users. The basic idea is simply sending username and password to get the user authenticated. And user can make request to server with the session_id without authenticating himself again.

Definitely, it is very insecure. But as far as I could understand now, in order not to expose the user's credentials, we can apply TLS(https) to get it encrypted.

However, as I research around, I get acquainted with a lot of concepts, like **Base64, HMAC_SHA1, API keys, OAuth1.0**. But I could not understand why do we need those mechanism other than TLS. Can anyone help explain why TSL is not enough to ensure authentication and API access to be secure?

Answer (score 0):

Secure sessions work fine if your web application authenticates the user, issues the session id and validates the id on each call. You can store the session id in a secure cookie that gets sent back on each request.

Things get more complicated when you have your API on a different domain. Now your cookies are not automatically sent to the service ([same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). You could of course stick the session id in an Authorization header when you call your API. But now your API needs to talk to the same backend store maintaining your session state to verify the authorization. This backend store becomes a bottleneck in scalability and a single point of failure.

To get around this, modern protocols (like OAuth2) issue security tokens. These tokens are [digitally signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) (using HMAC) and the receiver trusts the token if the signature is validated successfully. No backend calls are needed to validate the token, just a simple cryptographic operation.

API keys are used to allow applications to get a security token without relying on a user to authenticate. Think of them as a password for an application.

Using security tokens also allows you to use a 3rd party authorization server (like Facebook or Google etc) and completely get out of the business of authenticating users, storing passwords, issuing tokens etc.